# Elliptic Curve Multiplication Function

Tags: java, cryptography, multiplication, elliptic-curve

I'm trying to make my own library for the elliptic curve.
Some things work, but some others don't.

To calculate a public key from a private key, you should multiply the Generator Point with the private key, and you get another point: the public key Point (ECPoint = BigInteger * ECPoint).

Now, I have a private key, and I multiply it with the Generator Point of the Secp256k1 curve. I get a a key, but it is not the key I should get.

This is my JAVA code:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Point{

    public static final Point INFINITY = new Point();

    private final BigInteger x;
    private final BigInteger y;

    private Point(){
        this.x = null;
        this.y = null;
    }

    public Point(BigInteger x,BigInteger y){
        if(x==null || y==null){
            throw new NullPointerException("x or y is null");
        }
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public BigInteger getX(){
        return this.x;
    }

    public BigInteger getY(){
        return this.y;
    }

    public boolean isInfinite(){
        return this.x==null || this.y==null;
    }

    public Point add(Curve ec,Point Q){
        Point P = this;

        if(P.isInfinite()){
            return Q;
        }
        if(Q.isInfinite()){
            return P;
        }
        if(P.getX().equals(Q.getX()) && P.getY().equals(Q.getY())){
            return this.twice(ec);
        }

        BigInteger lambda = Q.getY().subtract(P.getY()).divide(Q.getX().subtract(P.getX()));

        BigInteger xR = lambda.pow(2).subtract(P.getX()).subtract(Q.getX());
        BigInteger yR = lambda.multiply(P.getX().subtract(xR)).subtract(P.getY());

        Point R = new Point(xR,yR);

        return R;
    }

    public Point twice(Curve ec){
        if(this.isInfinite()){
            return this;
        }

        BigInteger lambda = BigInteger.valueOf(3).multiply(this.getX().pow(2)).add(ec.getA()).divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2).multiply(this.getY()));

        BigInteger xR = lambda.pow(2).subtract(this.getX()).subtract(this.getX());
        BigInteger yR = lambda.multiply(this.getX().subtract(xR)).subtract(this.getY());

        Point R = new Point(xR,yR);

        return R;
    }

    public Point multiply(Curve ec,BigInteger k){
        //Point P = this;
        //Point R = Point.INFINITY;

        if(this.isInfinite()){
            return this;
        }

        if(k.signum()==0){
            return Point.INFINITY;
        }

        BigInteger h = k.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(3));
        Point neg = this.negate();
        Point R = this;

        for(int i=h.bitLength()-2;i>0;i--){
            R = R.twice(ec);

            boolean hBit = h.testBit(i);
            boolean eBit = k.testBit(i);

            if(hBit!=eBit){
                R = R.add(ec,(hBit?this:neg));
            }
        }

        return R;
    }

    public Point negate(){
        if(this.isInfinite()){
            return this;
        }

        return new Point(this.x,this.y.negate());
    }

}
```

Is there something with my code?
Is there a specific multiplier algorithm for secp256k1?

Comment: What is your input, expected output and the current output?

Comment: Input = 059E2BF5E2C7A4098C164B29A91CF70508D2FD1A256A60656FD2593BDB980FAA / Expected ouput = 04 + (DA43096D079CED007CDF810ECB27030FFBDBCCAB0400A5A040D282EF8049805B,A4F8D0BE0BDABE528524245B5BBD5A125835A302F61156CE6BE48530B8F53C66)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is something wrong with your code; you are trying to divide in Z (using BigInteger) when you need to divide in Zp (aka Z/pZ) where p is the curve parameter defining the underlying field (for secp256k1 see SEC2). Modular division is implemented in Java by taking the modular inverse and modular-multiplying; see [Scalar Multiplication of Point over elliptic Curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727147/scalar-multiplication-of-point-over-elliptic-curve) . Also you need to take at least the final results mod p, and it is usually more efficient to do the stepwise results as well.

Comment: It works, but the are this functions only for secp256k1 or only for Prime Curves? Where van I find a full documentation for Elliptic Curve (Prime, F2M, etc.)?

Comment: @BenvanHartingsveldt: Those formulas are for curves over a prime field in Weierstrass format, which includes the commonly used ones. I don't think there's full doc any one place because this is a new and still-changing field, but for the curves it covers I like the SECG docs at www.secg.org -- they include most of what I (and maybe you) need without huge amounts of digression and fluff. And of course Stack is always good, especially crypto.SX and security.SX :-)