# Generate EC public key from byte array private key in native java (7+)

Tags: java, public-key, elliptic-curve

I'm trying to learn some crypto coding and have generated a 32-byte private key currently held in a byte array (*byte[] privatekey*). I know the public key is generated using the *secp256k1* named elliptic curve parameters, and a formula where `publickey = G * privatekey`, where G is some point on the elliptic curve (ECPoint?), but I am unable to transfer that named parameter spec and formula into actual coding of a public key. I know that since java 7, there are classes included in the `java.security.*` and `java.security.spec.*` packages to do this in short code, but I can't find a good example showing how to do this without using a third party library.

[This bitcoin stackexchange link has all the theoretical answer and great python and C# code, but nothing in Java](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/25024/how-do-you-get-a-bitcoin-public-key-from-a-private-key).

Edit/Update: I have tried to get what I need with the following code:

```
String secp256k1_G_uncompressed_string = "0479BE667EF9DCBBAC55A06295CE870B07029BFCDB2DCE28D959F2815B16F81798483ADA7726A3C4655DA4FBFC0E1108A8FD17B448A68554199C47D08FFB10D4B8";
byte[] secp256k1_G_uncompressed_bytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(secp256k1_G_uncompressed_string);
String privatekeystring = "1184CD2CDD640CA42CFC3A091C51D549B2F016D454B2774019C2B2D2E08529FD";
byte[] privatekeybytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(privatekeystring);
BigInteger secp256k1_G_num = new BigInteger(1, secp256k1_G_uncompressed_bytes);
BigInteger privatekey_num = new BigInteger(1, privatekeybytes);
BigInteger curvepoint = secp256k1_G_num.multiply(privatekey_num);
byte[] publickeybytes = curvepoint.toByteArray();
System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(privatekeybytes));
System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(publickeybytes));
```

The publickey that should be generated with correct coding is this:

> 04d0988bfa799f7d7ef9ab3de97ef481cd0f75d2367ad456607647edde665d6f6
>   fbdd594388756a7beaf73b4822bc22d36e9bda7db82df2b8b623673eefc0b7495

but the public key that is being generated is this:

> 4E6801418BB6EF9F462F69830F82EB51BB9224219B9D89C8C34FB746297F59779D8B986194181BD7AB99DC7E3086914EA13C4B37E05716CADCA0AE391CE81C4B85E0F09E8628F0F81692B5D08D0D8B9E20615A5D23DE0F591D02C650554BB1D8

Comment: Maybe I should get the X and Y values of curvepoint and create and ECPoint from this and try to make publickey from the ECPoint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An elliptic curve point is not an integer. Putting the encoded representation of a point (G) in a `BigInteger` and trying to use it as an integer is nowhere near correct. Elliptic curve point multiplication is not integer multiplication, and is nowhere near as simple as `BigInteger.multiply`. And it is written with the scalar on the left, e.g. kG not Gk.

Translating the standard (or at least conventional) algorithms given at the bitcoin Q to Java really should be a reasonably simple exercise for any Java programmer.

[Scalar Multiplication of Point over elliptic Curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727147/scalar-multiplication-of-point-over-elliptic-curve) contains (in the answer) a correct implementation for P192 aka secp192r1; it can be converted to secp256k1 by replacing p and a with the values from the spec (SEC2 from https://www.secg.org or X9.62 if you have it) or any existing implementation -- including Java (see below) -- and discarding the P192-specific test data. Actually you mostly need to change p; the Koblitz curves were chosen to have a=0. [Elliptic Curve Multiplication Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45133489/elliptic-curve-multiplication-function) contains a not-quite-correct implementation that is stated to be for secp256k1 but doesn't actually include the constants for any curve.

> since java 7, there are classes included in the java.security.* and java.security.spec.* packages to do this in short code

Not really. First, Java crypto isolates the classes you see in `java.security` and `javax.crypto` from the implementation code, which is in entirely different classes (mostly (still) under `sun.*` and `com.sun.*`) in one or more 'providers' which are separate jars and technically optional; it is possible to remove, add, or change providers without changing the calls in your code, although most people don't. The JCA 'facade' classes for EC crypto were present since java 5 (called 1.5), but no provider implementing EC algorithms was included in the standard build; to use them you had to add a third-party provider. Starting in java 7 a standard SunEC provider IS included. However, JCA (for all algorithms not just EC) keeps private and public keys strictly separate after generation, and in particular it provides no way to access the private-to-public derivation logic that exists internally for EC.

It does include the parameters for several standard curves, including secp256k1, which you could use to avoid the effort of copying them from the spec. <strike>There doesn't appear to be a direct way to access this data, but you can do so indirectly by generating a nonce key and discarding it.</strike> Alternatively, since you already have a private key you can create the encoding Java uses (PKCS8) and read that in, producing the same curve parameters and also a usable key. In general constructing ASN.1 DER encodings like PKCS8 is fairly complicated, but *for EC* it is simplified because (1) everybody uses the 'named' form which encodes the curve as a single OID and (2) the standard specifies an encoding of the private value which is fixed in length for a given curve; as a result the PKCS8 encoding for a given EC curve consists of a fixed prefix followed by the private key value. Example snippets:

```
    /* this is not needed
    KeyPairGenerator kg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance ("EC");
    kg.initialize (new ECGenParameterSpec ("secp256k1"));
    ECParameterSpec p = ((ECPublicKey) kg.generateKeyPair().getPublic()).getParams();
    instead do the following: */
    AlgorithmParameters a = AlgorithmParameters.getInstance("EC");
    a.init(new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256k1"));
    ECParameterSpec p = a.getParameterSpec(ECParameterSpec.class);
    System.out.println ("p=(dec)" + ((ECFieldFp) p.getCurve().getField()).getP() );
    java.security.spec.ECPoint G = p.getGenerator(); 
    System.out.format ("Gx=(hex)%032x%n", G.getAffineX());
    System.out.format ("Gy=(hex)%032x%n", G.getAffineY());
    //
    byte[] privatekey_enc = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(
            "303E020100301006072A8648CE3D020106052B8104000A042730250201010420"+
            "1184CD2CDD640CA42CFC3A091C51D549B2F016D454B2774019C2B2D2E08529FD");
    // note fixed prefix for PKCS8-EC-secp256k1 plus your private value
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
    PrivateKey k1 = kf.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privatekey_enc));
    ECParameterSpec p2 = ((ECPrivateKey) k1).getParams();
    System.out.println ("again p=(dec)" + ((ECFieldFp) p2.getCurve().getField()).getP() );
```

which produces output:

```
p=(dec)115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663
Gx=(hex)79be667ef9dcbbac55a06295ce870b07029bfcdb2dce28d959f2815b16f81798
Gy=(hex)483ada7726a3c4655da4fbfc0e1108a8fd17b448a68554199c47d08ffb10d4b8
again p=(dec)115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663
```

Note those coordinates for the basepoint G match your expectation. I displayed a mix of decimal and hex just to show the possibilities; this does not affect the actual numbers in the computer.

ADDED in response to comments:

The variables p and p2 are `ECParameterSpec` objects which contain the parameters of an EC curve (underlying field, curve coefficients, basepoint aka generator, order and cofactor; and internally 'name' although the API doesn't expose it). The values I print labelled 'p' are the result of calling `getP` which returns *one* item from the curve parameters, namely the modulus of the underlying prime field, and thus the value you need to use in the calculations shown in the linked post where it does `mod(p)` and `modInverse(p)` and `modPow(,p)`. Since this p (or P) is a parameter of the curve it is the same for all keys on that curve; note the two values I print are the same even though they are from different keys. There are actually two kinds of elliptic curves standardized for cryptography: curves over a prime field, denoted Fp, and curves over an extension field of characteristic two, denoted F2m. secp256k1 is the first kind, that's why the cast to `ECFieldFp` before calling `getP()`.

Yes my fixed prefix contains the headers and fields identifying a privatekey (PKCS8) encoding as being for EC and secp256k1 and that prefix is the same for all EC secp256k1 privatekeys. The p values are as described above, and not privatekeys or publickeys. Yes if you had the public point you could combine it with the `ECParameterSpec` into an `ECPublicKeySpec` and convert it and use it -- or you could append the point encoding to a similar but different fixed prefix to get an `X509EncodedKeySpec` which is the encoding Java uses for publickeys and convert *that* without needing the `ECParameterSpec` in advance -- but your whole problem, as I understand it, is that you don't have the public point yet and want to derive it, which requires the point multiplication calculation shown in the linked posts.

Comment: Dave, thank you so much for the wonderful explanation. Truly very helpful. After running the code, I just have two questions... how did you get the fixed prefix for PKCS8-EC-secp256k1? Will that always be the static value or is that derived from my key in any way? If those bytes represent just the version and algorithm identifier, it seems like that becomes an always-constant value for what I am doing? and p is the 65-byte key in decimal format? Thanks again. Very helpful answer.

Comment: I think I may have answered my own question, in that when you print this:  ("p=(dec)" + ((ECFieldFp) p.getCurve().getField()).getP() ), that is not the public key. I am thinking it needs to end with something like this:  ECPublicKey k2 = (ECPublicKey)kf.generatePublic (new ECPublicKeySpec (point, p2));   and then p and p2 are used to get the points? Sorry, still struggle with all things math.

Comment: @godeatgod: much too long to respond in comments, see edit

Comment: +1 Thank you very much! I was looking for a way to use an existing private EC key in standard native Java. AlgorithmParameters made it much easier rather than creating ECParameterSpec from scratch with explicit domain parameters...