# Java: How to generate KeyPair form private key, using only pure Java.Security without BouncyCastle?

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle, public-key-encryption

`Java:` How to generate `KeyPair` form private key, using only pure `Java.Security` without third party provider like `BouncyCastle`?

I am using this code to generate `KeyPair`:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
ECGenParameterSpec ecSpec = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256k1");
keyGen.initialize(ecSpec, new SecureRandom());
KeyPair keyPair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
```

But what if I want to generate `KeyPair` from private key I already know?
I tried to find solution on web, but without success.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48832170/generate-ec-public-key-from-byte-array-private-key-in-native-java-7) ?

Comment: Java can only import private keys two ways: 1) PKCS8 format, either encrypted or not, or 2) using the individual BigInteger components, using private key spec classes together with parameter spec classes. The first way is usually much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

The public key in Java is just s * G where s is the private key (a vector) and G is the base point of the elliptic curve. However, there is no way to perform EC point calculations in Java, so you're stuck.

The one thing you can do is to lift the EC point calculations from an external library and use that. Well, OK, or you can perform the calculations yourself. Java does give you the option to retrieve the `BigInteger` values of s and the x and y values of G after all.

There is a roundabout way of doing the calculation by using ECDH (which basically **is** point multiplication, after all), but that's such a long workaround with so many hacks that performing the calculations yourself is much easier and cleaner.