# How do I create a PrivateKey object from private key bytes?

Tags: java, cryptography, jce

Say I have a seed: `this is a seed that i might have lying around somewhere`
I then hash the seed to produce a byte array of size 32
From what I understand (from [this](https://medium.com/coinmonks/how-to-generate-a-bitcoin-address-step-by-step-9d7fcbf1ad0b) article), this is now my private key bytes. How would I go around turning these bytes into a PrivateKey object?
From what I've seen, it is something like:

```
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
PrivateKey privateKey = kf.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyBytes));
```

But for this to work, the private key bytes should be in the PKCS #8 format. And since I generated my private key bytes by hashing a seed, they obviously aren't.

So my question is: how do I encode my private key bytes into PKCS #8, OR alternatively, is there another class to do this besides PKCS8EncodedKeySpec?

**I am using ECDSA**
**and**
**I am using secp256k1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... do I encode my private key bytes into PKCS #8, OR alternatively, is there another class to do this besides PKCS8EncodedKeySpec?

Yes and yes.

Option A: constructing a DER encoding like PKCS8 can be complex in general, but for the specific case of PKCS8-unencrypted containing an EC key in 'named' (OID) form, which is what everyone (and in particular Java crypto) uses nowadays, is simpler and for a given curve consists of a fixed prefix followed by the private key bytes. See my answer to [this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48832170/generate-ec-public-key-from-byte-array-private-key-in-native-java-7) which is mostly about the computation of publickey *from* privatekey, but my example uses the PKCS8-ized privatekey in the process of answering something else.

Note in java 9 up (released after that answer) `java.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter` is no longer available by default in JavaSE, so you either need to make it a dependency or substitute something functionally equivalent -- there are many Qs about this.

Option B: instead of using PKSC8 (encoded) representation, you can use [ECPrivateKeySpec](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/spec/ECPrivateKeySpec.html). <strike>As also noted in that answer, standard (Oracle/Open) Java doesn't provide an easy way to get the parameters alone, so the best I've found is to generate a dummy key and discard it:</strike>

```
/* workaround is unnecessary
KeyPairGenerator kg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
kg.init(new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256k1"));
ECParameterSpec param = ((ECPublicKey)kg.generateKeyPair().getPublic()).getParams();
--- instead do: */
AlgorithmParameters a = AlgorithmParameters.getInstance("EC");
a.init(new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256k1"));
ECParameterSpec p = a.getParameterSpec(ECParameterSpec.class);

BigInteger s = new BigInteger(1, /*byte[32] privatekey value*/);
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
PrivateKey kp = kf.generatePrivate(new ECPrivateKeySpec(s, param));
// castable to ECPrivateKey if desired/needed
```

If you instead use BouncyCastle's direct (non-JCA) API it does provide EC parameters by name; I can find some dupes for that if you want.

Caveat: if 'lying around somewhere' is NOT the output of a correctly implemented random process using sufficent entropy, and in particular the 'seed' is either chosen or remembered by a human, doing this is **insecure**. And if you use this for *Bitcoin* -- which you didn't say, but is the use case of most ignorant, untrained people who suddenly want to do ECC because they think it will make them sooper-kewl, l33t, rich, sexy and famous -- you will probably lose your money; see https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Brainwallet . But that's offtopic for StackOverflow.

Comment: I did something similar later on, i used ```AlgorithmParameters``` to get the param variable. Thanks