# java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: encoded key spec not recognized: failed to construct sequence from byte[] by generating ECDSA Signature

Tags: java, security, digital-signature, bouncycastle, private-key

I created a simple UserInterface that allows a user to send a transaction, similar to bitcoin. Among other things, the user must enter his private key (this is already encoded!). However, I have difficulties to create a signature from it.
My private Key is decoded like this:
SHA3Helper.digestToHex( ( ( BCECPrivateKey ) keyPair.getPrivate( ) ).getD( ).toByteArray( ) ) );
SHA3Helper is just to convert a byteArray to a String and acutally not very important here. I also use the secp256k1 elliptic curve.
Here is the method I use to create the signature:

```
public static byte[] GenerateSignature(String transaction, byte[] keyPriv) throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        byte[] privateKeyBytes = keyPriv;
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDSA");
        PrivateKey pKey = kf.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyBytes));
        Signature ecdsaSign = Signature.getInstance("ECDSA", "BC");
        ecdsaSign.initSign(pKey);
        ecdsaSign.update(transaction.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte[] signature = ecdsaSign.sign();
        System.out.println(signature.toString());
        return signature;
    }
```

Heres the simple method for reading the users input

```
@FXML
    void submitPressed(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Submit Pressed");
        byte[] sender = SHA3Helper.hexToDigest(senderField.getText());
        byte[] receiver = SHA3Helper.hexToDigest(receiverField.getText());
        double amount = Double.parseDouble(amountField.getText());
        double tfbp = Double.parseDouble(tfbpField.getText());
        double tfl = Double.parseDouble(tflField.getText());
        byte[] privateKey = SHA3Helper.hexToDigest(keyField.getText());
        Transaction transaction = new Transaction(sender, receiver, amount, 0, tfbp, tfl);
        System.out.println(transaction.getAmount());
        try {
            byte[] signature = SignatureHelper.GenerateSignature(transaction.asJSONString(), privateKey);
            transaction.setSignature(signature);
            System.out.println("Signatur: " + transaction.getSignature());
        } catch (Exception e) {     
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        DependencyManager.getPendingTransactions().addPendingTransaction(transaction);
    
    }
```

As you can see, I convert the privateKey string directly into a byte array and pass this to my generateSignature method.

Full Stack Trace:

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: encoded key spec not recognized: failed to construct sequence from byte[]: DEF length 112 object truncated by 82
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.util.BaseKeyFactorySpi.engineGeneratePrivate(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ec.KeyFactorySpi.engineGeneratePrivate(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyFactory.generatePrivate(KeyFactory.java:389)
    at main.utils.SignatureHelper.GenerateSignature(SignatureHelper.java:65)
    at main.Controller.submitPressed(Controller.java:50)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:84)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1852)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1724)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8923)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:207)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3894)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1887)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2620)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:551)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
```

It seems the error is probably in the conversion but I can't find it.

Comment: An X509EncodedKeySpec is only for *public* keys. A [`PKCS8EncodedSpec`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/security/spec/PKCS8EncodedKeySpec.html) is an example of a keyspec that supports private keys.

Comment: Thank you, i tried it with this one but now another error occours. I updated the questions. @President James K. Polk

Comment: That keyspec was just an example, I have no idea how your private key is actually encoded. PKCS8EncodedKeySpec is not a solution for every possible encoding of private keys, it works for one specific type of standard encoding.

Comment: Ah okay, my privateKey is encoded as follows: SHA3Helper.digestToHex( ( ( BCECPrivateKey ) keyPair.getPrivate( ) ).getD( ).toByteArray( ) ) ); SHA3Helper is just to convert a byteArray to a String and acutally not very important here. Do you know which keySpec should be used in this case?

Comment: Look at the Javadocs for [`KeySpec`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/security/spec/KeySpec.html). Look at "All Known Implementing Classes:". Some of those KeySpec are for elliptic curve private keys, like `ECPrivateKeySpec`, `EdECPrivateKeySpec`, and `XECPrivateKeySpec`. One of those should be appropriate. Perhaps if you shared more information about what kind elliptic curves you are using it would help. And please, don't respond with this important information in a comment, edit your question to add it along with the contents of your previous comment.

Comment: Thank you, i already updated the question with those informations. I use the secp256k1 curve

Comment: JCA PrivateKey for secp256k1 from raw bytes of d = dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68655241/how-do-i-create-a-privatekey-object-from-private-key-bytes and similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48832170/generate-ec-public-key-from-byte-array-private-key-in-native-java-7 . If you use `getInstance("EC")` (not `"ECDSA"`) in j7 up you don't need BouncyCastle provider. @PresidentJamesK.Polk: EdEC and XEC are for the Bernstein curves and algorithms, only, not SECG/X9/NIST curves like secp256k1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to reproduce the privateKey from the decodedBytes:

```
 public static PrivateKey getPrivateKeyFromBytes( byte[] privateKey ){
    PrivateKey result;
    try
    {
        ECNamedCurveParameterSpec spec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec( CURVE_NAME );
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance( ALGORITHM, PROVIDER );
        ECNamedCurveSpec params =
            new ECNamedCurveSpec( CURVE_NAME, spec.getCurve( ), spec.getG( ), spec.getN( ) );
        BigInteger s = new BigInteger(1, privateKey);
        ECPrivateKeySpec pubKeySpec = new ECPrivateKeySpec(s, params);
        result = kf.generatePrivate( pubKeySpec );
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        result = null;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Is this a second account of the same person who asked the question?