# ECpoint Scalar multiplication using p256 curve

Tags: java, cryptography, elliptic-curve

can anyone explain to me how to doing scalarmulti in curve p256? i currently stuck with this problem cant get new reference for this, only [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727147/scalar-multiplication-of-point-over-elliptic-curve) have closest issues same with me about scalar multiplication in java. any library i can use for this issues ?

Comment: The code you listed is a generic code, however, one must be careful to use it. What are you trying to achieve? Scalar multiplication is needed for the calculation of the public key from the private key, etc...

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ymnk/fec39e033394ee2ec47c ,  just change the curve...